# Gatling 3.8.4 problems when trying to switch from expressions ${} to #{}

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I have upgraded my project from Gatling 3.3.1 version to Gatling 3.8.4 version, my question specifically refers to Expression language I have an old version scala script created where there are several variables in the old style pattern "${}" so I want to change that into the new
pattern "#{}"

this is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
private def requestAndSaveSample(tokenVal: String) = {
http(s"logging user at: ${"/o/token"}")
.post(myApiUrl + "/o/token")
.headers(Map(("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")))
```

So when I try to change into #{"/o/token"}"). then I get some errors that I have been trying to solve, but no luck yet.

and also another question is related to handling these expressions at the endpoints, for example here:

```
http(s"List someSample by users")
.get(s"/v2/someSample/$entityId/userAssert")
```

when I change that to use the new pattern like this:

```
.get("/v2/someSample/#{entityId}/userAssert")
```

I get an error that says that the value does not exist.
Do you have any clue on this or any recommendation about some examples that provide a bit more information regarding the EL Gatling?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: `s"...${foo}..."` and `"...#{foo}..."` are different. In the former it's splicing done by Scala, it substitutes `foo.asString` into a `String` for a variable `foo` from a current scope. In the latter Scala itself doesn't do anything, `"...#{foo}..."` is just a such `String` from Scala point of view, with sharp symbol, curly braces etc. Handling (treating `foo` as a URL path element) is performed by the framework (Gatling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing:

- `s"${...}"` with the prepended `s` which is [Scala String interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)
- `"${...}"` without the prepended `s`, which is the deprecated Gatling Expression Language syntax, now replaced with `#{...}`

You must change the former, only the latter.

Comment: Thank you, Stephane, I have tried replacing only the ones with this expression       
 #{...} but besides that, I am having an issue with a value let's say for example I have this:  def authToken: Map[String, String] = {
  sampleHeader + ("Authorization" -> s"Bearer $${$authuthTokenVar}")  I see there is an interpolation and Gatlings complains with a warning that it is deprecated so when I tried replacing the old expression I am not getting the value of the variable, sorry about this but I got a bit confused.

Comment: @WillCG You should replace `s"Bearer $${$authuthTokenVar}"` with `s"Bearer #{$authuthTokenVar}"`

Comment: Awesome thank you! Dmytro Mitin, that helps a lot! it is working fine now.

Comment: Thank you! Stephane also for all the support, I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: No, you should replace s"Bearer $${$authuthTokenVar}" with "Bearer #{$authuthTokenVar}" without the prepending s.

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE I don't think so. If previously working was `("Authorization" -> s"Bearer $${$authuthTokenVar}")` (as OP stated in the comment) then `authuthTokenVar` was the name of Scala variable in current scope (`s"..."` is Scala interpolation, `$${...}` was Gatling older syntax `${...}`, just doubled to be escaped because of using `s"..."`). So now it should be `("Authorization" -> s"Bearer #{$authuthTokenVar}")`. What you propose `("Authorization" -> "Bearer #{$authuthTokenVar}")` would be correct if the token name was starting with a dollar `$authuthTokenVar`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin you're correct. I didn't get that `authuthTokenVar` was a constant for the name of attribute stored in the Gatling virtual user Session. So overly complicated.